# Selecting a folder created in automator, with another action in automator

Tags: automator

I am relatively new to using Automator and I have been tasked with coming up with a way to duplicate files into multiple folders, as well as adding those images into subfolders.

I need to make a folder of images duplicate into two other separate folders, while deleting the originals after duplication. I have that part figured out and up and running without any problems.

But the next part has me stumped. I need to create a subfolder with the name 'Backup' with today's time on it, which I have done as well. Unfortunately, I need to move the duplicated files into it and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it.

So the process is as follows:

1. Files dumped into 'Originals' folder
2. Files duplicated into 'Backup' and 'Retouch' folders
3. Deleting of files from 'Originals'
4. Creation of new subfolders in Backup  and Retouch with a time stamp added to it
5. Moving of files from Backup and Retouch, into Backup and Retouch subfolders (with timestamps)

It has taken me this long to create all this, and I'd like to do it all automated without anyone having to select any files at all after starting the folder action. If there is any help that you might give me in this endeavor, I'd appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Automator.  Is this a code question or a software usability question?  If it is software usability it probably belongs at Super User.

Comment: Its a coding question. I haven't figured out how to move the duplicated files into the 'backup' folder without using manual interference.
I need to figure out how to move it automatically via the system, and not user input.